# Handling writes & consistent reads until leader lease expires

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, distributed-system, leader-election, leader

The DynamoDB paper (https://www.usenix.org/system/files/atc22-elhemali.pdf) mentions that for replication they use Multi-Paxos, and leaders are assigned for a lease.

In case of leader failure,

> The new leader won't serve any writes or consistent reads until the previous leader's lease expires

Let's say the leader was assigned at T1, with lease until T1 + 100.

At, T1 + 50; the replicas detect the leader is not responsive so go ahead with leader election; then how is serving the consistent reads and writes until T1 + 50 to T1 + 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that time frame when a new leader is being elected, you are subject to either timeout exceptions or more likely InternalServerErrors which returns a 5XX to the client. Clients have built in backoff and retry which usually overcomes any leader election issues, so writes and strongly consistent reads will be eventually served, albeit with a higher latency.

Comment: Since leader going down is more often (rollouts; network partitions etc.) hence I am assuming returning 5XX to client is desired to be minimum. How long typically it takes for a leader to be assigned to a replica? and how long are the leases for?

Comment: The lease duration is implementation detail which is not publicly disclosed, however I can say they default settings for the SDK retries take those timings into account.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll get an internal server error response during that short time window for writes or strongly consistent reads targeting the partition that is electing a new leader. Reads and writes to other partitions will be unaffected.